# Python find value of attribute with lxml

Tags: python, lxml

How am i gonna be able to get the value of data-sku with from lxml import html

```
<button data-e2e="product-size"    type="button" class="btn btn-default "
data-price="DKK 1,750.00"
data-sku="050226_jdsportsdk.006458"
data-brand="Nike"
title="Vælg størrelse 42"
>
            42
            <span class="fulfilment-notice-html hide">
```

That is the html ^^.

i tried `xpath('//button[@data-e2e="product-size"]//@data-sku()')` 
but doesnt work

I want to get the value of data-sku, so that would be "050226_jdsportsdk.006458". I do not know that its going to be "050226_jdsportsdk.006458", so thats why i need some way of scraping that part.

Thanks

Comment: Does your xpath work without those weird parentheses at the end? And without the second set of double `//` – it should only need one.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, that gives me a error in the CMD

"lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression"

Comment: i found out a way to fix it!

Comment: Great! You are allowed – and even encouraged – to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), and after a short waiting period you can also accept it. (Just don't make the mistake to edit it into your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to fix it!

i had () after the @data-sku, and also a double //,

the right answer is `xpath('//button[@data-e2e="product-size"]/@data-sku')`